# There's error when I use template : Compiler Error C2770: invalid explicit template_or_generic argument(s) for 'template'

Tags: c++, templates

You may notice that I've study strassen algorithm.
I used template for both float and int type. 
But there happes template error : Compiler Error C2784 'declaration' : could not deduce template argument for 'type' from 'type'
Please help me whats wrong and how can I fix it

You can see the whole codes in 
https://github.com/hyunseoki/matrix_multiplication/blob/master/matrix_multiplication/matrix_multiplication/Strassen.h

```
template<typename T, size_t N>
void MatrixMult_Strassen(const T A[N][N], const T B[N][N], T C[N][N])
{   int i, j;
    const int mid = N / 2;

    if (N == 2) 
    {  
        MatrixMult_OpenMP<T, N>(A, B, C);
        return;
    }

    T A_11[mid][mid], A_12[mid][mid], A_21[mid][mid], A_22[mid][mid],
        B_11[mid][mid], B_12[mid][mid], B_21[mid][mid], B_22[mid][mid],
        C_11[mid][mid], C_12[mid][mid], C_21[mid][mid], C_22[mid][mid],
        M_1[mid][mid], M_2[mid][mid], M_3[mid][mid], M_4[mid][mid],
        M_5[mid][mid], M_6[mid][mid], M_7[mid][mid], temp_A[mid][mid], temp_B[mid][mid];

    //Matrix Division
    for (i = 0; i < mid; i++)
    {
        for (j =0; j < mid ; j++)
        {
            A_11[i][j] = A[i][j];
            A_12[i][j] = A[i][j + mid];
            A_21[i][j] = A[i + mid][j];
            A_22[i][j] = A[i + mid][j + mid];

            B_11[i][j] = B[i][j];
            B_12[i][j] = B[i][j + mid];
            B_21[i][j] = B[i + mid][j];
            B_22[i][j] = B[i + mid][j + mid];
        }
    }

    MatrixSum<T, mid>(A_11, A_22, temp_A);
    MatrixSum<T, mid>(B_11, B_22, temp_B);

    MatrixMult_Strassen<T, mid>(A_11, A_22, temp_A); // here error occurs

// below codes are ommited

}
```

Comment: I don't really see how that can line of code can produce that error message. Please add a compilable example.

Comment: Thanks for reply. You may compile whole the solution.. it only consists of 2 files main.cpp and strassen.h main cpp : https://github.com/hyunseoki/matrix_multiplication/blob/master/matrix_multiplication/matrix_multiplication/main.cpp headfile : https://github.com/hyunseoki/matrix_multiplication/blob/master/matrix_multiplication/matrix_multiplication/Strassen.h

Comment: It produces a different error message for me. It tries to instantiate functions with `N=0`. I think you may need to use `if constexpr(N==2)`, and put the part after the return in the else branch.